# What does & (ampersand) mean when used in this context?

Tags: ruby, operators

I'm trying to understand the use of inject in the `contents_support?` method in this Array class. What is the purpose of the `&` operator/how is it working? I assume it is the bitwise and operator. I found this explanation of the `&` operator:

> Possibly the simplest use of the binary & operator is in the Array class. `&` is the set-intersection operator, which means the result is a collection of the common elements in both arrays.
>
> ```
> irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3] & [1,2,5,6]
> => [1, 2]
> ```

But what does that mean in this case, where `true` is passed as an argument to `inject` where some of the objects (i.e. the local variables `items`) might not respond to the message sent. Can you explain what `contents_support?` returns and why `&` is necessary? Is the above mentioned code snippet explaining `&` the proper way to think about `&` in the code below?

```
class Array
   def contents_support?(message)      
      self.inject(true) { |all_ok, item| all_ok = all_ok & item.respond_to?(message) }       
   end

   def thunk(message, *args)
      if contents_support?(message)
        self.each { |item| args.empty? ? item.send(message) : item.send(message, args) }
      else
        raise "Not all contents of #{self.inspect} respond to method #{message}"       
      end   
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most operators in Ruby, `&` is overloaded: its behaviour depends on the types of its arguments.

- In your first snippet, the objects on either side of `&` are `Array`s. In that case, `&` is something like set intersection: the resulting `Array` only contains an element if it is found in both arguments of `&`.
- In your second snippet, the left hand side is a boolean. Clearly, that means that `.respond_to?` must return a boolean (the question mark at the end of the name should be a hint). In case of boolean values, `&` is logical conjunction: if both sides are `true`, the result is `true`, and otherwise it's `false`.

Comment: thanks, I thought & had to be && to make it a logical conjunction, but I guess that's javascript only

Comment: `&` is bitwise `and`; `&&` is logical `and`.

Comment: @Zabba: not in Ruby, thanks to overloading. `&` is just some binary operator.

Comment: @Tinctorius, also see [bitwise operations](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_bignum.html#Bignum.Bitoperations)

Comment: @Zabba: that's about the implementation in the `Bignum` class, not the general meaning of the operators.

Answer (score 3):

Something Tinctorius did not say.
In your cas, the usage of `&` is not relevant, you could have used `&&`. It would have been actually better for performance.

```
a & b
```

executes `a` *AND* `b` and returns their combined result.

```
a && b # equals if a
       #          return b
       #        else
       #          return a
       #        end
```

Which means, *it does not execute `b`* if `a` is falsey. In your case, you do not need to check `item.respond_to?(message)` if `all_ok` is false.

By the way, `contents_support?(message)` could have been written simpler using [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F).

```
def contents_support?(message)
  self.all? { |item| item.respond_to?(message) }       
end
```

And since you asked, `contents_support?(message)` test if all items of an array support `message` which could be an attribute or a method. ex: `[1, 2, 3].contents_support?(:next) #=> true`